# Replace the query string param using jQuery and put it in the address bar without refreshing

Tags: jquery, jquery-address

I have to replace the st=6 to st=7 using jQuery or JavaScript and update the address bar. I tried using the jQuery address plug in but I can replace only the part after the #.

Could you please suggest how do I update the query string before the #.
The query string is mentioned below.

`http://test.com/search/searchresults?st=6&term=chicken#/?term=chicken&pi=1&ps=10`

I don't want to refresh the page on changing the url but need to change the url in the address bar.

Comment: Your main  question is not how to actually replace st=6 to be st=7, but how you replace it in the address bar? if so then you should make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to update the actual url in the address bar you then this is a new feature of HTML5 and not widely supported.

For example:

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

Looking at caniuse.com it seems that this is upcoming in the next major versions of all browsers:

- http://www.caniuse.com/#search=pushState

You can still change the url but it will cause the page to reload by using `window.location = "http://www.example.com/";`

You should be able to use the other regex in this page to build the url you want to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str = 'http://test.com/search/searchresults?st=6&term=chicken#/?term=chicken&pi=1&ps=10';
str.replace(/(st\=)\d+&/, "$1" + '7'); // replace '7' with any number you like
```

It's not jQuery, it's javascript (the stuff jQuery is made of :) via a [Regular Expression](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp), and it should do the job in your case.

Comment: how do I replace the url in the address bar

Comment: window.location.replace(str.replace(/(st\=)\d+&/, "$1" + '7'));

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression, like this:

```
var addr = 'http://test.com/search/searchresults?st=6&term=chicken#/?term=chicken&pi=1&ps=10';
var newVal = 7;

addr.replace(/([?&])st=\d+/, '$1st=' + newVal);
```

Comment: how do I replace in the address bar

Answer (score 0):

I think what you ask for is not achievable, think of a bank login form page where you replace the current url with the real bank url, this would cause major security issues.